# How to make a div draggable from just 1 on of its child nodes

Tags: html

I am using the `draggable` attribute to enable reordering of elements like the following . I detect the various drag events and can interpret these to reorder the array of data to show.

[image]

The problem is that I attach `draggable` to the row as a whole to get the visual effect I want from the browser, but I cannot now select the text "Two" using the mouse, because it is being interpreted as a drag event. Attaching `draggable="false"` to the input did not help.

The ideal UI would that you have to drag from the drag-icon but that when you do, you see the whole row of elements move (at least in Chrome as I know draggable can look different between browsers).

One option might be to use a blurry png of the row [specify the drag Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#dragfeedback), but ideally it would be an the live data

Comment: Are you using the `handle` attribute? Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zfpxw2a2/

Comment: hmm that seems to be jquery draggable.I was talking about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to add event listener to the drag icon such that when the mouse was over the parent node was given the draggable attribute at that time. That prevented dragging from any other part of the component as well as the artifact when trying to select text -  a double win